# Numbering items in a paginated ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm having a hard time coming up with a good way to number the items in my paginated ListView. The solution I was using prior to adding pagination worked fine, but now the numbering doesn't persist between pages. If the first page is 1-10, the next page will also be 1-10 and so on. Obviously, it should be 1-10, 11-21, etc.

Is there an easier way to add numbering to ListView items that I'm missing? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show ListViewItem.Index property. Note that it's zero-based.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.index.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like this?

(PageIndex*PageSize)+ItemIndex

Comment: How would you get the current page index?